# Python parse data from single string

Tags: python, string, parsing

Parse name, age, gender from given str.

```
input: 
str = "musleh23malejemi22femaletanjir26male"

output:
Name: musleh, Age: 23, Gender: male
Name: jemi Age: 22, Gender: female
Name: tanjir, Age: 26, Gender: male
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
import re

text = "musleh23malejemi22femaletanjir26male"
chunks = re.split(r"\d+}", text)
```

this isn't working however. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`regular expression`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

s1 = "musleh23malejemi22femaletanjir26male"
pattern = r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)(male|female)+"
for match in re.finditer(pattern, s1):
    print(match.groups())
```

Out:

```
('musleh', '23', 'male')
('jemi', '22', 'female')
('tanjir', '26', 'male')
```